# Non-Reeb vector fields on the three-sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

*Let $X$ be the Hopf vector field on the three-sphere. Is there a smooth nowhere zero function $f$ so that the modified vector field $fX$ is not the Reeb vector field of *any* contact form on the three-sphere?*

This question is a follow-up on [aglearner's](https://mathoverflow.net/users/13441/aglearner) interesting [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259390/reeb-flows-on-s3-versus-volume-preserving-flows) on how to construct volume-preserving flows on the three-sphere that are not Reeb vector fields.

I'm also looking for evidence to support the following **guess**: *If $X$ is a vector field on the three-sphere, there exists a nowhere zero smooth function $f$ so that the vector field $fX$ is not a Reeb vector field for any contact form on the three-sphere.*

Comment: If you can make sure that $fX$ has at most one closed orbit, you violate Cristofaro-Gardiner--Hutching's refinement of Taubes' theorems (a.k.a. the Weinstein conjecture).

Comment: @MarcoGolla,  I think Reeb flows are really special and I'm looking for easier arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

**Proposition.** *Let $\alpha$ be the standard contact form on the three-sphere (for which the Reeb vector field is the Hopf vector field $X$). If $f$ is a strictly positive function on $S^3$ such there exist two Hopf circles $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ for which
$$
\int_{\gamma_1} f^{-1} \alpha \neq \int_{\gamma_2} f^{-1} \alpha \ ,
$$
then the vector field $fX$ is not the Reeb vector field of any contact form on $S^3$.*

The key idea is that all solutions of $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))X(x(t))$ are periodic and that if $fX$ were a Reeb vector field, all these solutions would have the same period.

Indeed, assume $fX$ is the Reeb vector field of a contact form $\beta$. If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are integral curves of $fX$ with periods $T_1$ and $T_2$, then
$$
T_2 - T_1 = \int_{\gamma_2} \beta - \int_{\gamma_1} \beta = \int_\Sigma d\beta \ , 
$$
where $\Sigma$ is a cylinder with boundary $\gamma_2 - \gamma_1$ and foliated by Hopf circles (I'm being a bit sloppy with the word *foliated*). It follows that this last integral is zero and so $T_1 = T_2$.

Now we just have to notice that the period of $\gamma_i$ ($i = 1, 2$) equals
the integral of $f^{-1}\alpha$ over $\gamma_i$:
$$
\int_{\gamma_i} f^{-1} \alpha = \int_0^{T_i} f^{-1}(\gamma_i(t))\alpha(\dot{\gamma_i}(t)) \, dt = \int_0^{T_i} f^{-1}(\gamma_i(t))\alpha(f(\gamma_i(t)) X(\gamma_i(t))) \, dt = T_i
$$